# Unnest multi-index dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have multi-index dataframe in pandas with names (A,B,C..), features (F1,..FN) and dates. At every date, each of the names have a value for each of the features. Reading the data gives me the following df:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path,header=[0,1],index_col=0)
df =
   Name  A                                  B                        C  ...
   Ft    F1 F2 F3           ...       F_N   F1 F2 F3    ...    F_N   F1 ...
   date
   1/1   1  4  1            ...        3    3  2  2             1    5  ...
   1/2   4  3  3            ...        1    5  1  2             1    4  ...
```

I now want to restructure it so the names and dates appear multiple times as separate rows instead in order to reduce the amount of columns:

```
df =
       
   date Name    F1 F2 F3           ...       F_N   
   1/1  A       1  4  1            ...        3     
   1/1  B       3  2  2            ...        1
   ...  ...       ...              ...       ...
   1/2  A       4  3  3            ...        1     
   1/2  B       5  1  2            ...        1
   ...
```

I've tried different ways of unpacking & exploding but none seems to get me the results I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple matter of using `stack` and then, optionally, `reset_index` if you do not like the multi-index:

```
df.stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    level_0    Name      F1    F2    F3
--  ---------  ------  ----  ----  ----
 0  1/1        A          1     4     1
 1  1/1        B          3     2     2
 2  1/2        A          4     3     3
 3  1/2        B          5     1     2
```